# How to pass private integer from Class A to another Int Variable in Class B in C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, parameter-passing

Basically, I have 2 classes, "Car" and "Motor". "Car" has setMotor, which should take in an Motor object, when a motor is already available, and inherit the power of the Motor and output its power by saying "brum" for each PS the motor has. If "powerofmotor" is 3, then the car has to make "brumbrumbrum" when the move function is called.

I am using Codeblocks, so the code samples are divided into headers, cpp files and a main file.

### Headers:

**car.h**

```
class Car:
{

public:


    void setMotor(Motor m);
    void move();
    Car();

private:    
    int powerofcar = 0;
};
```

**motor.h**

```
class Motor{

friend class Car;

public:
    Motor();
    Motor(int p); //assign the power -> Motor(3) has 3 PS

private:
    int powerofmotor = 0;

}
```

### Cpp Files:

**car.cpp**

```
Car::Car(){
}

void Car::setMotor(Motor m){

powerofcar = m.powerofmotor;


}

void Car::move(){


if(powerofcar != 0){
    for(int i = 0; i < powerofcar; i++){
        cout << "Brum";
    }
cout << endl;
}


else {
    cout << "i move without a motor" << endl;

}
}
```

**motor.cpp**

```
using namespace std;


Motor::Motor(){
}


Motor::Motor(int p){

powerofmotor = p;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
Motor* m1 = new Motor(3);
Car *c1 = new Car;
c1 -> setMotor(m1); // <--- doesnt work "converation error"
c1 -> move();
}
```

Using the code below i get "error: invalid conversation from 'Motor*' to 'int' 
 [-fpermissive]"

if i type "c1 -> setMotor(*m1) then i get "i am moving without a motor", so basically the else statement is called.

The expected Output should be "BrumBrumBrum" because the Car should have 3PS after i assign a motor with 3PS to it.

Comment: Your `setMotor(Motor m);` takes a `Motor` by value (meaning it will make a copy of a `Motor` that you pass it. You gave it a `Motor*` Depending on your design goals you probably want to change what setMotor() takes.

Comment: BTW, C++ is not C# nor Java.  You do not need to use `new` for every object.

Comment: There is a `:` after `struct Car` that is not necessary.

Comment: That is one question I have. Why are you using `new` at all?

Comment: Your `Car` class doesn't have any `Motor` member, so a `setMotor` method is useless.

Comment: It would be better to present a [mcve] (focus on minimal). Half of the code that you show (for example all the include stuff) is not necessary to explain the problem and only makes it harder for others to get down to the relevant stuff and to help you.

Comment: Why is `Motor` a friend of `Car`?  If you are modelling an automobile, then `Motor` should be a member of `Car` because a `Car` *has-a* `Motor`.  You don't usually see operational cars with their motors disconnected (and located outside, anyplace) (e.g. `friend` relationship).

Comment: You have an incorrect type assignment.  The `Car` class is assigning a `Motor` type to an `int` (`powerOfMotor`).  Maybe you need a `Motor::powerOf` method that returns a copy of the `Motor`s power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I'm in a good mood, I'll give you some foundation:

```
class Motor
{
  public:
    Motor(int power)
    : m_power(power)
    { ; }

    Motor() : m_power(0) { }

    int get_power()
    { return m_power;}

  private:
    int m_power;
};

class Car
{
  public:  
    Car()
    { ; }

    Car(Motor& m)
    : m_motor(m)
    { ; }

    get_power()
    {
      return m_motor.get_power();
    }
  private:
    Motor m_motor;
};
```

In the above example, `Car` can be constructed with a *default* `Motor`, or you can construct a `Car` with a `Motor` of your choosing:

```
int main()
{
  Car ford_edge;  // Car with default motor.
  Motor v16(16);  // Create a v-16 motor.
  Car muscle_car(v16);  // Create a muscle car with a v16 motor.
  cout <<  "Muscle car has power of: "
       <<  muscle_car.get_power() << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are passing pointer to Motor(`Motor*`) to function `void setMotor(Motor m);` when it is expecting a value type(`Motor`).

Change `Motor* m1 = new Motor(3);` in main function to `Motor m1(3);`.

---

If you need to pass a pointer only for some reason, then you change `c1->setMotor(m1);` to `c1-> setMotor(*m1);` but this would create a copy of object since you are not using reference or change the signature of `void setMotor(Motor m);` to `void setMotor(Motor* m);` as shown below.

```
void Car::setMotor(Motor * m) {
    powerofcar = m->powerofmotor;
}
```

Comment: i need to structure my function based on the given main.cpp file from my proffesor. How do i write setMotor to take a pointer the right way?

Comment: @informatiker I  have updated the answer based on your requirements. I would recommend you to go through pointers, value and reference types to understand the concepts better.

Comment: Or, there's also `setMotor(*m1)` too.

Comment: OP:  preference should be given to references.  A pointer can point to anywhere, including invalid locations (addresses).  A reference points to a known, existing, object.

Comment: @SolidMercury At first I couldn't find where the OP said that, then I read the comments before mine, lol. That makes sense now. Still, in general, that is another way to solve the problem, provided you could change the main (for anyone in the future reading this).

Comment: @Chipster Yes chipster. But it would simply create a copy as OP is not using reference. Anyway updated that as well.

Comment: Thanks ! your solution is quite easy and works perfectly! What to do you mean by "Or, there's also setMotor(*m1) too" ??

Comment: @informatiker Wanted to update one more possible solution but edited in wrong place. Corrected it now. if you think the answer has helped,  you can accept it so that people can focus on unanswered questions or if you need more info, feel free to ask.